# kafka-connect error: ORA-01882 timezone region not found for configuration docker

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm running confluent platform on docker and playing around. Followed the steps to install ojdbc8.jar driver and environment seems to be up and running without any errors.

Getting below error when I configure the connector from the control center. [image]

Driver seems to be the correct because I get "no suitable driver found" error when I tried ojdbc10.jar

I tried passing below configs together & separate ..nothing helps.

```
  CONNECT_OPTS: "-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false"
  CONNECT_USER_TIMEZONE: "+01:00"
```

wondering whats the proper method to set this configuration ?

Comment: Those aren't valid environment variables for the Connect container, and wouldn't be passed to the SQL connection string anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add generic JVM opts, you'd set `KAFKA_OPTS`.

Neither `CONNECT_OPTS` nor `CONNECT_USER_TIMEZONE` are loaded by the container's processes.

So, try

```
KAFKA_OPTS: "-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false -Duser.timezone=Europe/London"
```